# Calling two levels of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In SQL Server 2014 I have two stored procedures. One calls the other with the `INSERT` command.

I want to call the upper stored procedure to get the result table of it. However, I get an error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Procedure HelloWorld, Line 23
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

This is an example of my completed code:

1st stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HelloWorld_2]
    @aaa VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS col1, @aaa AS col2
END
```

2nd stored procedure (it calls the 1st stored procedure)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HelloWorld]
    @aaa VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temp TABLE(col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR(20))

    INSERT INTO @temp
        EXEC [HelloWorld_2] @aaa

    SELECT *, 'patata' 
    FROM @temp
END
```

SQL that I need to execute (it calls the 2nd stored procedure)

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR(20), col3 VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @temp
    EXEC HelloWorld 3
```

The return values has to be a table with 3 columns and 1 row. But this error appears:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

However the temp table is correct with the column order and values...

Comment: I can't replicate that error ([DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=100fc262fe525d0a188c51f15234b2d3)), I get `Msg 8164 Level 16 State 1 Line 6
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.`; which you can't fix. This looks like an XY Problem.

Comment: SQL is not a procedural language, so callstacks like this are problematic at best.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Brian, well, I'm trying to use some existing SP that I already create. We are using both SP in production so I don't want to modify them and I don't want to create another SP.

Comment: Well, as @Larnu said, you've run into a limitation with SQL Server. What I typically do in a situation like this is create a `#Temp` table in the top level procedure - `HellowWorld` in your case - and take advantage of the fact that procedures that it calls - `HelloWorld_2` in your case - can see it. However, you have to document that sort of thing pretty heavily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all replies.

Finally, I create a function of 'HelloWorld_2', so the stored procedure 'HelloWorld' and the SQL code works correctly.